# Universal App Loading Different Views

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios6, ios-universal-app

Trying to make an existing app having two different set of .h .m and .xib files for each view. Now for a single view am using only one .h & .m file and two .xib file.
eg.
ViewController.h, ViewController.m, ViewController~iphone.xib, ViewController~ipad.xib

Problem: At compile time i get errors for the files in my code i have not set their target for iphone and ipad both.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Project -> Targets -> Build Settings -> Targeted Device Family . Set it to iPhone/iPad.

Enjoy Programming!!

Answer (score 0):

Better solution is add target device for existing class